# Connecting classes and assigning values

Tags: python

I've created two classes one called `Offense` and the other `Defense`. I'm having trouble making it so that a user can pick the `run` play and when the plays go against each other the greater play wins. I believe I've done the inheritance correctly on the `Defense` class by adding the `Offense` class to the argument of the `Defense` class. But after creating a rule that the `offense` play is less than the `defense` play IN the Defense class, nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
class Offense():
    def __init__(self):
        self.play1 = 'run'
off_1 = Offense()




class Defense(Offense):
    def __init__(self):
        self.play1 = 'run'

defen_1 = Defense()
off_1.play1 < defen_1.play1

if off_1.play1 < defen_1.play1:
    print("Defense wins")
```

Comment: There's no reason to use inheritance here: `Defense` is not a kind of `Offense` (no jokes about "best defense is a good offense, please).

Comment: All `off_1.play1 < defen_1.play1` does is compare one value to the other. It doesn't magically *make* the first value less than the second.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use operator overloading on the `__lt__, __gt__, __eq__` operators to compare plays, perhaps? Or just a dict that maps the play types to a numeric value?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? You do not need to pass the parent class through the defense class as your defining the instances in the defense class. When you pass the parent class through you inherit the instances in to the sub class.

Comment: @chepner i understand what you're saying.

Comment: @glibdud I didnt know that thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @G.Anderson i am trying to figure out the best way to compare plays where i set them as one will beat the other the best way possible.

Comment: @Barb thank you so much. Im just trying to make the plays go against each other and print the winner depending on the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to do nothing to compare "greatness" of the plays.  It checks whether the *name* of the offensive play is alphabetically before the *name* of the defensive play.  It isn't -- the two are equal -- so your code prints nothing.

You have no "rule" that offense is less than defense.  You did insert a boolean expression and throw away the result, but that does not constitute a "rule".  Python has no such structure: you would need to implement it yourself.

Overall, I believe that you need to work through your program design again.  Decide what properties you want and implement those.  Perhaps you'll want a `Play` class, with both `Offense` and `Defense` inheriting from that; perhaps you'll merely have two instances of `Play`, one each for offense and defense.

However, to compare which is "greater", I would think that you'd want some numerical evaluation of the combination.  Your posted code has no such function.

Comment: Thank you i did actually make a play class but got overwhelmed. What you said makes perfect sense.

Comment: Good.  It appears to me that you need to solidify the design of your game engine before doing more implementation.  The design drives the data representation and control flow; *that* drives you coding design.  This means that you're two major steps short of having your next Stack Overflow question.  :-)